# Sharepoint 2016 and compatibility version of Microsoft identity manger server( MIM) server

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, 2016, mim

Hi what is the compatibility version of Microsoft identity manager server with share point 2016?

We have a SharePoint 2016 farm and want to import user profiles from active directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Identity Manager 2016 supported for SharePoint 2016. You can use MIM 2016 or MIM 2016 SP1.

Read this Pnp post for complete information. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/UserProfile.MIMSync

> Prerequisites
>
> Documentation in the repository calls out prerequisites, such as:
>
> Microsoft Identity Manager 2016
>   Microsoft Identity Manager 2016 Update
>   SharePoint Connector for FIM